# Can a lightsaber hilt be made out of cortosis?

Tags: star-wars, technology, star-wars-legends, lightsaber

Let's say I'm a Jedi.

If I constructed a lightsaber hilt out of Cortosis, would the lightsaber work?  If it did, could I then hit another lightsaber-wielder's blade with my hilt, short out that person's lightsaber, then use mine to quickly supply a coup de grace?

Has a lightsaber user ever done this?

[Blame ShemSeger for inspiring this question.](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/110917/why-arent-lightsabers-made-out-of-mandalorian-iron)

Comment: I'm going to stop posting questions for the day now.  Thanks!

Comment: Question... why make the **hilt** of cortosis, instead of cross-guard? That would be a better tactical approach (you can tell I designed weapons in the past :)

Comment: @DVK because I'd make my hilt a little bit longer to serve as a slapjack of sorts, so I could swing it at another lightsaber wielder's blade, short out the weapon, then gracefully spin 360 degrees while igniting my lightsaber and lop off his head on the backswing.  It would be awesome.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Considering that hilts can be [made out of wood,](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Gungi's_lightsaber) there is no reason you wouldn't be able to make a hilt out of [Cortosis](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Cortosis/Legends).

**Legends:**

> Cortosis ore was a very rare, brittle, fibrous material whose conductive properties caused lightsabers to temporarily short out upon contact.

It would appear that a cortosis hilt, when struck by a saber, would cause the opponent's blade to short out.

To avoid your own blade shorting out, the inside of the hilt would need to be made of different material with the protective cortosis being only on the outside.

> Only lightsabers that used a special kind of lightsaber crystal mined on Mestare were immune to the effects of cortosis.

A hilt made of cortosis that also uses this special crystal from Mestare would probably be even less likely to cause its own blade to short out.

> Cortosis was expensive to mine because it was so rare and it had to be absolutely refined.

Since the material is rare and sometimes even dangerous (in it's pure form), it's unlikely many Jedi would seek to build their hilts from it under normal circumstances. Jedi train for lightsaber combat, so they'd simply try to train themselves to avoid leaving their hilts open to attack.

Comment: Presumably your own blade would also short out.

Comment: @Richard would it if the lightsaber elements inside were sheathed in some other metal?

Comment: @SSumner - Dunno.

Comment: Or just wear a chainmail or buckler made out of cortosis, and force contact, proceed to destroy the enemy when he has no saber

Comment: @Oak: The difference in material quantity of a lightsaber hilt and a suit of armor, or even a shield, would be pretty staggering. That's relevant simply because the material is already crazy expensive due to it's rarity. I think your best bet might be to fire the cortosis as a super-fast projectile, thus requiring your force-wielding opponent to block them with their lightsabers. Then proceed to cut them down. Bonus points if you can recover the projectiles afterwards.

Comment: True, however it only needs to contact, you don't necessarly need a full buckler. Let's say you manage to process down the material into a sheet (like they do with furniture). It's a really low ammount. Cut a droid's head, grab it by its neck, place a little tiny bit of the material on its head, and proceed to use it as a shield. You only need it to deactivate the enemy's saber, not for it to be strong or anything. Don't forget that Jedi only deflect shots because they can, they could also jump and dodge them

Comment: I think the better material to use would be Beskar'gam or Mandolorian Iron, it's resistant to lightsabers (and by default almost anything else in the Galaxy) and it wouldn't run the risk of shorting out your own lightsaber since that is not one of its properties it's probably the more practical for a lightsaber hilt than cortosis the only problem is that it belongs to the Mandalorians and they don't like to share with Jedi.

Comment: @TheMandolorian but I'm not afraid it's going to be destroyed, I'd want to be able to negate the Jedi's weapon.  I think I just let it slip I'm a Dark Jedi.

Comment: @Nate I was just telling you how I'd make a lightsaber I have a great appreciation for the Mandalorians and in fact I would want to be trained by them if possible and as for being a Dark Jedi you aren't alone I'm one to.