# Are actual lightsaber crossguards effective?

Tags: star-wars, lightsaber, star-wars-rebels

Referring to [Useless cross-guard on a lightsaber?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/73922/useless-cross-guard-on-a-lightsaber/) fans here should be very familiar with the crossguard debate when Kylo Ren's lightsaber was first revealed. However, we've since proven that those are actually vents for excess energy from Kylo's flawed crystal.

Since then, we've observed a Jedi's lightsaber bearing the same crossguards. In *Twilight of the Apprentice*, we see Ezra pick up an ancient Jedi lightsaber that ignited fully, *including two crossguard blades as stable, controlled beams*, before the entire weapon shorted out due to age.

That didn't appear to be vented energy. It looks exactly the same as the main blade, like Anakin/Luke/Finn/Rey's lightsaber's blades. But on that note, Kylo's vented energies look kinda like the flawed main blade too. But then again, if the crystal hadn't been flawed, those side vents would never have been needed (resulting in the classic lightsaber), suggesting the ancient lightsaber's crystal wasn't flawed (given the stable blade), and so the crossguards might have been there for intents different from Kylo's.

Are those (the ancient Jedi lightsaber) really crossguards and not some design with a primarily utility function? If it's really a crossguard, how does it serve as an effective combat component? Does the old discussion over Kylo's now-proven-to-be-not-primarily-a-crossguard hold true here?

Comment: That's the difference. Ezra's cross-guard lightsaber has two *side-blades*. Kylo Ren's saber has vents to allow waste plasma to vent. There's no indication that Kylo's crossguards can stop a saber strike.

Comment: So are we on agreement that those are combat capable blades? Then, does in matter in the Jedi saber's case that there are metal parts jutting out of the sideblade emitter parts?

Comment: I'd assume that you'd simply make those bits out of a material that can resist a saber strike. And yes, they have every appearance of being combat - capable.

Comment: I'm suddenly reminded of all the lightsabers destroyed in that same episode. Maybe lightsaber resistance isn't that important a design consideration after all...

Comment: Why would you put crossguards on a lightsaber if they didn't work?

Comment: @cheese - So your enemy would be confused or intimidated in some fashion

Comment: The beam may actually be emitted from within the central hilt, rather than the metal pieces on the side.  Either way, even if *only* the visible part of the blade is actually capable of blocking a saber, it'd still be better than not having any guard at all.  *With* a guard, you only need to move your hand one inch to block a blow aimed at your wrist.  *Without* a guard, you have to move your hand all the way up from the core of Bespin.

Comment: @Liesmith: Bah-dum-dum!

Comment: Define effective. Ren used his cross guard effectively to further incapacitate Finn by driving one of the guards into Finn's shoulder.

Comment: @richard CHEESE please, not cheese.  But okay.

Comment: @Liesmith that shade!

Comment: Cross-guards on a lightsaber would have the same effectiveness on a lightsaber that they did on broadswords. That is to say increased defense, decreased mobility. It gives more protection to your wrist and hand but makes it slightly more difficult twirl it about. Rather if you have Crossguards your going to want to opt towards strong powerful strikes that are meant to batter and disarm (which we see Kylo Ren doing by the way) rather than flurry attacks that are meant confuse and distract.

Comment: One thing I've noticed is that in the final battle, Obi-Wan dismembered Grievous because lightsabers lacked crossguards - Obi-Wan locked sabers with Grievous but simply slided his blade down. You don't see that happen to Jedi and Sith - maybe Force training helps protect you against attacks normally guarded against by crossguards, which is why they were no longer used in practice until Kylo Ren's time?

Comment: Isn't there some property of the lightsaber blade that makes it "stick" to other lightsaber blades, negating the need for a crossguard (to protect your hand from swords sliding down your blade)? No source, so I might be remembering things wrong.

Comment: @chif-ii While they're supposed to stick, we see people lose hands via sliding.

Answer (score 6):

To know if a cross guard on a light saber would have worked we have to look at how the Jedi fight. The Jedi fighting consisted of 7 different forms. (Found [here](https://goo.gl/WeW0W) ) Because of the nature of this question we will be looking at form 2, Makashi, which was a form base solely on dueling other light saber wielders.

To determine whether a cross guard could be an effective tool while fighting we have to look at what Cross guards were originally used for. Traditionally cross guards were used to protect a wielders hand in real world combat. (Info found [here](https://goo.gl/hKrPZD) ) So this brings us back to fighting style of Makasi, which was a fighting style developed to counter the fighting style of Shii-Cho which was a fighting style based on disarmament of an opponent. In most cases the easiest way to achieve this was to remove the hand holding the opponents light saber. An example of this is in the battle between General Grievous and Obi-Wan in which Obi-Wan defeats Grievous by cutting off his hands hold his light sabers.

So in a sense a cross guard on a light saber does make some sense, as a protection to deflect blows close to the wielders hand. But in practice it is not truly known which fighting style Kylo Ren uses, (Although I am personally pretty sure it is Juyo the fighting style of channeling ones emotions to fight) we won't know his uses in a fight with a cross guard, although it can be said that in the hands of a master of the first two forms of light saber fighting it could be a useful tool.