# What do we know about the technological difference behind Kylo Ren's lightsaber?

Tags: star-wars, lightsaber

After watching the latest trailer, there are three main points I feel needs to be addressed:

- How is the crossguard constructed? Is it similar to a double-bladed saber's construction of using multiple crystals to achieve the emittance of multiple blades?
- Why does Kylo Ren's saber flicker? Seeing as the blue saber Finn was wielding in the trailer is similar to a good old Jedi lightsaber, we can conclude this isn't a new CGI style, and thus likely have an in-universe explanation. Are there functional differences to it - for example different combat characteristics, or perhaps it is unable to achieve zero energy leak?
- Overall, is it a technological advancement, a "primitive homemade device" or simply a variant on a roughly similar level of technology?

Comment: Given that the rest of us also only have the trailers to go off of, I doubt you'd get any more than guessing games. Isn't your question asking people to speculate on unreleased material?

Comment: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/103331/how-is-kylo-rens-lightsaber-able-to-have-a-cross-at-the-hilt

Comment: I was wondering if there was any talk of it in, say, novels and such

Comment: Similar question: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/73788/has-the-lightsaber-cross-guard-from-the-star-wars-7-teaser-trailer-been-seen-bef As to Finn's Lightsaber, I'm pretty sure I read somewhere that it is Luke's, which is probably why it looks like a "good old Jedi lightsaber".

Comment: "_three_ main points" - pun intended.

Comment: Stephen Colbert addressed this starting at 3:12 in the following clip https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ycg_3vhOfTk

Comment: Closing per our future works policy.

Comment: @Catija Luke's? You mean Anakin's old one that fell out of cloud city, or did he make a blue one later?

Comment: @CBredlow Luke's original one, yes... the one that used to be Anakin's.

Comment: Alrighty, since I can't post this as an answer due to it being speculation but here's a picture of Kylo Ren's lightsaber: http://cdn.collider.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/star-wars-7-kylo-ren-lightsaber-1-600x338.jpg

See how it looks cobbled together, whereas most lightsabers are elegant pieces of art (Even Luke, a barely trained one, has a beautiful lightsaber). This is led some people to believe that this cobbled together-ness is the reason the beams look more like flames/all wavey vs a straight line you see anywhere else.